# Why ALB is not launching after successfully creating ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to launch application load balancer(ALB) on AWS EKS. I have already installed Application load balancer controller in my cluster successfully. The tutorial I am following tells me that after creating ingress and applying it, I should see an ALB created in my AWS, which I don't. What could be the reason? Am I missing something?

I have already created and started apple-service and banana-service and their pods too.

Here's the ingress YAML. I can successfully apply this ingress also, but the ALB didn't launch.

I am using EKS k8s **version 1.22**

```
kubectl -n kube-system get deployment
NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
aws-load-balancer-controller   2/2     2            2           19m
coredns                        2/2     2            2           38m
```

```
kubectl get ingress
NAME                     CLASS    HOSTS             ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
my-awesome-app-ingress   <none>   testingkarlo.ml             80      14m
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-awesome-app-ingress
  labels:
    app: my-awesome-app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
  - host: testingkarlo.ml
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /apple
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: apple-service
              port:
                number: 5678
        - path: /banana
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: banana-service
              port:
                number: 5678
```

**apple.yaml**

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-app
  labels:
    app: apple
spec:
  containers:
    - name: apple-app
      image: hashicorp/http-echo
      args:
        - "-text=apple"

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: apple-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: apple
  ports:
    - port: 5678 # Default port for image
      targetPort: 5678
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**banana.yaml** is similar as above.

After applying apple.yaml and banana.yaml ,Two classic Load balancers are launched in AWS.

Comment: is there any error in controller pod logs?

Comment: @HarshManvar No.

Comment: Your service has to be of type "ClusterIP", not "LoadBalancer". That's why there are two LBs. Which version of the AWS load balancer controller did you install? Newer versions should create ALB for ingresses and NLB for services of type "LoadBalancer".

Answer (score 0):

In the yaml file the class is missing, by default it brings up classic load balancer.

Another possiblity if no load balancer comes up it can be:

If the IAM looks fine across the cluster, the issue can be also due to VPC link.

The error we faced for the ALB before deleting was :

> Failed deploy model due to RequestError: send request failed caused
> by: Post "https://elasticloadbalancing.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/":
> dial tcp 172.20.4.51:443: i/o timeout

Which led to deleting the ingress and recreation, but while recreation the ingress was up in the EKS without any errors but not in AWS Load Balancer console

The culprit was the VPC enpoint created for API gateway by us, deleting the VPC link resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the following steps to identify the issue

```
 1. Identify the errors in the controller pod
 2. Check the IAM policies again. follow this document for more info on the IAM policies. https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/deploy/installation/
 3. Add the tags to subnets follow this -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help anyone.
My ALB was not created. So, looking at the logs from my POD aws-load-balancer-controller, I saw the following message: "error":"multiple subnets in same Availability Zone.

To resolve this, I configured just two subnets in my ingress.yaml, in the alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets annotations and reapplied the ingress.yaml.